# Clap - default value for PathBuf

Tags: rust, clap

How can I set the default value for clap PathBuf argument? Is it even doable? I keep bumping from one error to another.

When I try doing it the "Struct" way:

```
use std::{env, path::PathBuf};
use clap::{Parser, Args};

fn get_default_log_path() -> PathBuf {
    let mut path = env::current_exe().unwrap();
    path.pop();
    path.push("log/debug.log");
    path
}

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
struct Cli {
  #[arg(default_value_t=get_default_log_path())]
  log_path: PathBuf
}

fn main() {
  let args = Cli::parse();
  println!("{:?}", args);
}
```

I get: `std::path::PathBuf doesn't implement std::fmt::Display...`

When I try it with string:

```
#[arg(default_value = get_default_log_path().as_os_str())]
log_path: PathBuf
```

I get: `temporary value dropped while borrowed`

And if I do .to_owned() on that it outputs: `the trait bound clap::builder::OsStr: From<OsString> is not satisfied`

Is this even possible or am I doing something wrong? I know it can be done with `Option<PathBuf>` and deal with it in main function. But can this be done this way or nah?

Comment: Hey! Please make sure that the code you post actually produces the error you claim it does. Your first example produces `error: mismatched closing delimiter: "]"`.

Comment: Fixed. Missed one closing `)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Due to the fact that the default values get printed in the help (`--help`/`-h`) page, they have to implement `Display`.

`PathBuf` sadly doesn't do so, so you can't use `default_value_t` to provide a default for it. You can, however, use `default_value` without a problem.

The next problem you will face is that by default, clap only supports static string references for default values. To enable dynamic, owned values for defaults, you need to enable the `string` feature of clap in your `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
clap = { version = "4.3.0", features = ["derive", "string"] }
```

Then, the following works:

```rust
use clap::Parser;
use std::{env, path::PathBuf};

fn get_default_log_path() -> PathBuf {
    let mut path = env::current_exe().unwrap();
    path.pop();
    path.push("log/debug.log");
    path
}

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
struct Cli {
    #[arg(default_value=get_default_log_path().into_os_string())]
    log_path: PathBuf,
}

fn main() {
    let args = Cli::parse();
    println!("{:?}", args);
}
```

```
$ cargo build --release
...

$ target\release\rust-tmp.exe
Cli { log_path: "D:\\Projects\\rust-tmp\\target\\release\\log/debug.log" }

$ target\release\rust-tmp.exe --help
Cli { log_path: "D:\\Projects\\rust-tmp\\target\\release\\log/debug.log" }

D:\Projects\rust-tmp>target\release\rust-tmp.exe --help
Usage: rust-tmp.exe [LOG_PATH]

Arguments:
  [LOG_PATH]  [default: D:\Projects\rust-tmp\target\release\log/debug.log]

Options:
  -h, --help  Print help
```

Be aware of the mixed `/` and `\`, though. Don't use `/` in a `PathBuf` - use multiple `push()`s instead. Like this:

```rust
use clap::Parser;
use std::{env, path::PathBuf};

fn get_default_log_path() -> PathBuf {
    let mut path = env::current_exe().unwrap();
    path.pop();
    path.push("log");
    path.push("debug.log");
    path
}

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
struct Cli {
    #[arg(default_value=get_default_log_path().into_os_string())]
    log_path: PathBuf,
}

fn main() {
    let args = Cli::parse();
    println!("{:?}", args);
}
```

```
Cli { log_path: "D:\\Projects\\rust-tmp\\target\\release\\log\\debug.log" }
```

Comment: I can't rellly just use a string - I can, i just can't figure out how to get it from PathBuf without above error. For abrevity I've left that part out, but in my real code I'm using a function that returns a PathBuf. I've updated my question.